# How to make a quick window to rename tab

Tags: c#, winforms

So I tried to make a form that renames tabs like this.

[image: SOQ62463491]

It is written in WPF and I don't know how to write the same thing in WinForms. Here is the WPF code:

```
public partial class TabEditWindow : Window
{
    public TabEditWindow(TabControl tabs)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.tabs = tabs;
        base.Topmost = true;        
    }


    public void Show(TabItem tab)
    {
        this.tab = tab;
        base.Show();
    }

    private void RenameTab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Hide();
        TextBox textBox = this.tab.Header as TextBox;
        textBox.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox.Focus();
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void CloseTab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Hide();
        this.tabs.Items.Remove(this.tab);
    }

    private TabControl tabs;        
    private TabItem tab;
}
```

That was the WPF code. I haven't tried anything because I cant think of any ways.

Comment: To do the exact same thing in winforms would be overly difficult and fiddly. however you could make a small dialog (or use the built in one to change the tab header

Comment: @TheGeneral There is a built in changer?? I cant seem to change it still... Give me an example please

Comment: There is no built in changer. however there are context menus and dialog boxes. and you can set the tab header in code

Comment: Try [Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms).